# "Days in column" dots explanation

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I'm trying to work out the logic behind the Days in Column dots on JIRA boards but can't quite get it right.

It's *almost* the following:

1. A grey dot is 1 day
2. An orange dot is 2 days
3. A red dot is 3 days
4. Only show dots for up to 12 days

But those rules don't work for a handful of cases.

Here's my data, taken from a snapshot of one of my boards:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16oGvpQomtJEaS6hmhNfFaDub-4nafmi1jJ32PYMSyvQ/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone know the logic behind this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the "Using Days in column" on [the online help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/customizing-cards-764478020.html#Customizingcards-UsingDaysincolumn):

> Blank dot → 1 day
>   Grey dot → 2 days
>   Yellow dot → 3 days
>   1 red dot → 5 days
>   2 red dots → 8 days
>   3 red dots → 12 days
>   4 red dots → 20 or more days
>
> Note that if you move an issue back to a column where it's previously been, the indicator gives you the cumulative number of days the issue has stayed in that column.

The logic has also changed recently according to [this post](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWCLOUD-16004?focusedCommentId=1517953&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1517953) stating "the new dots behaviour is available only in Cloud".

There is an [outstanding bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-11847) where the weekends are counted as days. This might explain why your data doesn't align.